# Python how to use JSON dumps on a nested JSON to avoid double encoding

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

I'm reading a CSV from S3 using the following code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')
bucket = "bucket"
key = "key"

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
fieldnames = [i for i in range(0,13)]
lines1 = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
testls = [row for row in csv.DictReader(lines1[1:], fieldnames)]
out = json.dumps([row for row in testls])
```

but the problem is one of the fields in the CSV is a JSON , so the resulting JSON string from the last step ends up looking like this:

```
 {"Date": "2020-03-02 15:18:10.724017", "First?": "", "metadata": "{\"field1\":\"NULL\"}"}
```

how can I avoid this?

Comment: Is that a bad thing? If you want to keep the json string as a string then json will have to escape it. You could do `row["metadata"] = json.loads(row["metadata"])` if you want to expand the metadata to a python dict. You'll likely want to unwrap that list comprehension to a for loop.

Comment: Can't you just deserialize that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the metadata into a python dict as you read the rows so that it will be integrated into the json string. As a side note, testls is already a list, no need for that extra list comprehension.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')
bucket = "bucket"
key = "key"

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
fieldnames = [i for i in range(0,13)]
lines1 = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
testls = []
for row in csv.DictReader(lines1[1:], fieldnames):
    row["metadata"] = json.loads(row["metadata"])
    testls.append(row)
out = json.dumps(testls)
```